# Passing state down as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-proptypes

I have my main component called `App`.

`App` pulls in the `Table` component like so:

```
<Table
  players={players}
/>
```

`players` is initially defined in the `App` component's state as an empty array but inside my `Table` component I do this:

```
console.log(this.props.players, 'players');
```

Why would I get `undefined`?

I also have this inside my `App` component:

```
render() {
   const { players, matches } = this.state;
```

Comment: You need to pass as this.state.players. It is undefined because players is inside your state, so you need the this.state before players

Comment: @GabrielMesquita ah crap I should have said. i have const players = {this.state.players} inside my `render()` function

Comment: haha I see.  So this changes my answer a little :)

Comment: Please post the entire code so we can take a better look :)

Comment: In that case you need to put `const {players} = this.state;`

Comment: @GabrielMesquita thanks so much but im an idiot. i had called <Table /> above with no props but i was calling it on the second time. working now. thanks again!

Comment: Haha @TheWalrus no problem :) good luck and if it helped remember to mark the answers as correct

Comment: @TheWalrus you said players is in the component state, however you are calling it as a prop... why you don't post your entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment in your question you need to do something like this:

```
<Table
  players={this.state.players}
/>
```

This way you are getting players from inside your state. Without "this.state" you will receive and undefined error

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the `object` / `array` from the `state` like this

```
this.props.state.players`
```

Or you can use the [Destructuring assignment of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like so:

```
 const { players } = this.state;
```

Example:

```js
const Table = ({ players }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          players.map(player => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {player}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      players: ['john', 'alex', 'chris', 'dan']
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { players } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Table players={players} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your updated question, it really depends on how you set up your `Table` component.

- If its a stateless component you should be able to access the players
  directly without using `this.props.players`.
- If its a `class` component then it should be working as expected but
  maybe you have other piece of code that may cause this behavior.

You didn't share enough code for us to know.